# Generate url using input tag

Tags: javascript, html

for example i need to check DHL tracking number and i asking user to enter their tracking number to check it. here is input:

```
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" >
<button onclick="myFunction()">check tracking</button>
```

And DHL making it adding code tu url for example:  `https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode=` and plus tracking codehere. The demo url is this: `https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode=48484848484848484`

Here is Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
var inputed_code = document.getElementById("myText").value ;
var dhlurl = "https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode="
var new_url = dhlurl + inputed_code ;
    window.open("new_url", "_blank");
}
```

But it doesn't url as it is needed :(

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `"new_url"`, which is a literal strting, instead of `new_url`, the variable

```
function myFunction() {
var inputed_code = document.getElementById("myText").value ;
var dhlurl = "https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode="
var new_url = dhlurl + inputed_code ;
window.open(new_url, "_blank");
```

}

Comment: it doesnt open new tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript - it can't